# Meena and Seema are playing cards. Probability and counting principle.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Meena and Seema are playing cards (ace has 1 point, jack has 11 points, queen has 12 points, & king has 13 points). If Meena gets a jack, what is the probability that she would win?

In my book the answer given is $\frac{10}{13}$
But I strongly doubt to it...
My answer:

> **First approach:**
>   Case 1 : if meena gets first chance and she picks up jack, and Seema gets a second chance.
>   When meena picks , she has to pick one among all the 4 types (club,spade,heart,diamond) of Jacks.(so probability is $\frac{4}{52}$)
>   And then after one is gone then there are 51 cards left (..here I am assuming without replacement...is my assumption right...??)
>   Now when Seema has to pick she has to pick either of the Ace to 10 (i.e. 10 cards out of every type...so 10*4=40 choices as favourable out of 51 left..)
>   (Thus Seema probabilty will be $\frac{40}{51}$)
>   So Probability will be $$\frac{4}{52}.\frac{40}{51}$$
>   Case 2 : if Seema picks first and then meena picks...
>   Whenever Seema pick she has to again the one with value less than jack (i.e. 11), for meena to win ..
>   So probabilty for Seema is $\frac{40}{52}$
>   And now for meena is $\frac{4}{51}$
>   ..(bcoz I am assuming without replacement...)
>   So the total probabilty is $$\frac{40}{52}.\frac{4}{51}$$
>   So thus the total probabilty for both cases is sum of the two probabilities..
>   $$\frac{4}{52}.\frac{40}{51}+\frac{40}{52}.\frac{4}{51}$$
>
> **Second Approach**:
>   Here I am goofing up with sure event definition...I think sure means that has to come so it's probabilty is 1
>   Thus as meena gets Jack so her probabilty is 1
>   Now either seema could get chance after meena (in that case her probabilty would be $\frac{40}{51}$) or before meena (in that case her probabilty would be $\frac{40}{52}$)
>   So thus the total probabilty is $$(1).\frac{40}{51}+\frac{40}{52}.(1)$$
>   (I think I am goofing up with sure event...plz help whether this approach is right...)
>
> Plz tell which of my approach is right and why...(or am I totally mistaking....some where..)

Comment: What happens if they both get a jack?  Do they tie or do they draw again?

Answer (score 2):

On the assumption that if Seema draws a jack they tie so Meena does not win and Seema draws from what is left in the deck after Meena's draw, if Meena draws a jack there are $40$ cards it beats and $11$ cards it does not beat.  Her chance of winning is then $\frac {40}{51} \gt \frac {10}{13}$.  To get the book answer we have to assume Seema draws with replacement, so Meena's card goes back in the deck, the deck is shuffled, and Seema draws.  Then there are $40$ cards Meena beats and $12$ she does not, giving a chance to win of $\frac {10}{13}$.  When asking problems like this it is important to specify the rules carefully.

Answer (score 0):

probabilitu biggest card is jack and meena gets it=$\frac{{4 \choose 1}{40 \choose 1}}{{52 \choose 2}}\times \frac{1}{2}$ = a

Probability meena gets a jack = $\frac{1}{13}$=b

Answer is $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{40}{51}$ ,so yeah i think your book is wrong (and i am assuming jack vs jack is a tie).

Your first method is correct but you should also consider it's probability $\frac{1}{2}$ on who starts. Then also divide your answer by $\frac{1}{13}$ because it's a conditional probability.